# Inconsistent responses with 'eth_getTransactionByHash' through RPC API. Can anyone help?

Tags: go-ethereum, ether, json-rpc, python

I have been using the requests library with python to query the geth/rpc api in order to get ETH transaction data. I connected to geth via "geth --rpc --unlock TESTINGADDRESSWITHNOVALUE --allow-insecure-unlock".

Sometimes when I query a transaction hash (it seems to be only very old transactions) I get the appropriate response ex: tx_hash = 0xff2c55c1f2be6cb89f5d2486a6d56f2856664eddf65b3ddd7b4ee1c06b01f66f. Yielding the response:

```
{'blockHash': '0x44a6c685d3cf6764a0c7f9fd5f6fadddf7db73fb6cdefcf428674fd354e57753', 'blockNumber': '0x425709', 'from': '0xc32ee26a67b9084773bc16a1ae81b8660a39a40f', 'gas': '0x61a80', 'gasPrice': '0x2540be400', 'hash': '0x6424958d16a6b687d29ef7ef1289d9fbaf96c9b0c7ef7c618b2a58ed580145af', 'input': '0x', 'nonce': '0x3', 'to': '0xb72a0fa1e537c956dfca72711c468efd81270468', 'transactionIndex': '0x5b', 'value': '0x35e285658ff2480000', 'v': '0x25', 'r': '0xdc01e389077bcba1812eee246174e28a12ba1b2b793c87f00e231ee269c01ed9', 's': '0x265d600e38a837f3ae4e3377fc6a5eac14c75bbb15c0fca8fe5829a3cccb62ce'}
```

Other times the response I get from newer transactions is simply "None". For example, the recent transaction: "0x453ce623c545c6d3294595e9e0640ffdb49be3a6b9e4ced13a657d2cedac85c6". Does anybody know why this may be the case? Please let me know if there is more information I can provide. Thanks!